# Why does storage overview on my Mac say 50GB is used when I don’t see that much data stored in my Documents folder?

Tags: macos, mac, storage

My Mac’s storage overview is saying there is 50GB used up in my Documents but as you can see there isn’t close to that being utilized. Is it possible there are hidden files?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My Mac’s storage overview is saying there is 50 GB used up in my Documents but as you can see there isn’t close to that being utilized.

This issue has already been addressed on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341938/why-the-storage-of-documents-showing-wrong-in-mac) and boils down to the fact that many users do not realize that the "Documents" category under the Storage tab refers to:

**The total amount of space occupied by all files with certain file extensions anywhere on the hard drive.**

The "Documents" category does *not* refer to:

**The amount of space occupied by the contents of the "Documents" folder.**

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: @JakeGould: It looks like the images weren't changed. They both have the same Imgur URL as mine originally did and they look identical. Not sure what you did here!

Comment: I prefixed the images with quote arrows: `>`. It gives it a quote background so the image has some kind of border/bufffer to make it easier to differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

The first screenshot you posted is showing the storage level of your Mac's internal hard drive. This total includes any file with a common document extension, not just items in your **Documents** folder. Also note that the second screenshot is looking at your iCloud documents folder, which is only showing local cached data being synced to Apple's cloud service.

To identify the largest files on your internal hard drive, [follow the steps](http://osxdaily.com/2012/04/17/find-large-files-in-mac-os-x-search/) for running a Finder search based on file size:

> 1. From the Mac OS Desktop, open any new Finder window
> 2. Hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up Search
> 3. Click on “Kind” filter and select “Other”, then select “File Size” from the attribute list
> 4. Click on the second filter and choose “is greater than”
> 5. In the third space, enter the size to search for anything greater than (ex: 100) and choose either MB or GB as the final filter

Comment: Good answer. But to the best of my knowledge, when one chooses to sync their documents to the iCloud, the Documents folder by default is based in the iCloud directory. So the screenshot and description don’t contradict each other.

Comment: You should point out that the "Documents" referenced in the first screenshot isn't a description of the space used by the actual Documents *folder* but rather of all "document" files anywhere on the hard drive: .pdf, .doc, .docx, .psd etc. That's where all this confusion is coming from. A lot of users seem to think that the "Documents" under the Storage tab is simply describing how much data is in that one folder.

Comment: Updated first paragraph to clarify document terminology.

Comment: @skippy619 *"Also note that the second screenshot is looking at your iCloud documents folder, which is only showing data synced to Apple's cloud service."* The contents of your iCloud drive are *cached locally* and so *are* contributing to the amount of space occupied by "documents" as they are PDF files. There is only about 1 MB of data there but it *is* being included in the total you see under the Storage tab. JakeGould, it doesn't only save to the cloud: "iCloud Drive is a syncing service, not a cloud-only storage service." https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7458393

Answer (score 0):

Marking Mr Ethernet as correct but in addition, I also found that I had to unhide my library folder to see that it was taking up 45gb of the 50. Everything adds up now!

Answer (score 0):

Fire up a copy of OmniDiskSweeper and you can see the storage information for all folders on the hard disk. Here is one example: [folder storage details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOdv4.jpg)